# Apache Camel: Send empty body ws

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

How can i call a SOAP web service with an empty message body using Apache Camel?

For example, the final endpoint on a route would be the invocation of a method on my proxy that takes 0 arguments.

EDIT:

example xml configuration:

```
<route id="someRoute">
            <from uri="ref:activemq-queue"/>
            <setHeader headerName="operationName">
                <constant>invoke</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="cxf:bean:someWS"/>
</route>

...

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="someWS" address="${ws.address}"
                     serviceClass="com.example.ws.SomeWS"
```

The problem is that the method 'invoke' on the WS takes 0 arguments, and an exception is thrown stating that 1 argument is being received. Is there a way for me to specify to ignore this received input?

Comment: Have you found this bug? 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7069

Answer (score 1):

You can set the message body to be null, if the invocation just take 0 argument. null simple expression is added since camel 2.12.3.

```
<route id="someRoute">
            <from uri="ref:activemq-queue"/>
            <setBody>
               <simple>null</simple>
            </setBody>
            <setHeader headerName="operationName">
                <constant>invoke</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="cxf:bean:someWS"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Hi. this answer is incorrect. I still receive "null" as string from the response.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to set an empty body to Apache Camel xml and the solution below worked for me.

```
        <setBody id="set-empty-body">
            <constant/>
        </setBody>
```

Hope this helps to whoever need it.

Answer (score 0):

The xml configuration will fail if the content of the body is not with the correct type of the class required by the method of your bean. By default, it could be an `Object` and not a `String`. When the method recieves the body in an incorrect format, it would process a `null` value, instead of the body of the route. To **solve** this problem, you will need to convert the body into the expected class of the method of your bean. For example, if the method's argument of the bean is a `String`, then you could do something like:

```
<route id="someRoute">
    <from uri="ref:activemq-queue"/>
    <setHeader headerName="operationName">
        <constant>invoke</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
    <to uri="cxf:bean:someWS"/>
</route>
```

For more information about *body conversion*, you can check the docs: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/convertBodyTo-eip.html